# Web View not playing audio

Tags: android, android-webview

I am testing with a web content just using  tags to show videos.

the content is rendered properly in chrome.
But for the same audio is not being played in the web view.

My code for the web view

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri webUri = intent.getData();
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        Log.i(TAG, "User Agent used in the web view " + webViewSettings.getUserAgentString());
        Log.i(TAG, "URL to be loaded " + webUri.toString());
        webView.loadUrl(webUri.toString());
```

We just use video tags so there should not be any incompatibility problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Saurav

Comment: how did you solve this? please tag me if you got solution?